# How to write every character from a string in a CSV?

Tags: c#, csv

When writing to a `CSV`, semi-colon and other character are not written in excel (since semi-colon are used to separate cell).

I tried to escape semi-colon with \, however it doesn't seem to work like this:

```
mystring.Replace(";", "\\;");
```

what would be the proper way to write in a csv the semi-colon?

Also, are there any other character which will be interpreted and not shown in the csv?

Comment: There are libraries for reading/writing CSV data like http://filehelpers.net

Comment: Sounds more like a problem with Excel than with csv. Turn off that "feature" in Excel, use a different client for viewing your csv files, or try putting quotes around strings that include semicolons.

Comment: @PaulHicks make sense, I think I will find something ese than excel to read it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I tried to escape semi-colon with \, however it doesn't seem to work
>   like this

To escape semicolon you need to enclose the whole string into double quotes.

```
using (var fs = new StreamWriter("test.csv"))
{
    fs.WriteLine("Col1;Col2");
    fs.WriteLine("\"Test;Me\"" + ";" + "Now");
}
```